# -bash: ... command not found npm

Tags: express, global, npm-install

I’m getting that message after installing `express` globally.

I went through most of the solutions related to the /.bash_profile file and about exporting the correct PATH, but it still nothing works.

I tried this solution https://superuser.com/a/1081802 and it worked on the terminal, but when I close it and tried to execute the command `express`  followed by the file I wanted to use, it ended up showing the same message.

Please help!

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Answer (score 1):

So I was looking for other kinds of solutions, and I remembered that I installed via the website and not by home-brew. Just in case, I uninstalled it and installed node again.

I run this:

```
 npm install express -g
 npm install express-generator -g
```

And up to this point it is now working.